# which way is best to store our application settings in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an Android Application which requires some data to be save. So to fulfill that requirement to save the application data I used sqlite database and save all the application as well as user data in database table.

But when I add the new field in the database table then it generate following problem: Installing this latest application with new added field of database table will generate conflict.

Can any one tell me which is the best way to store our application settings?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use SharedPreferences.

For an example and more information see the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html